# OIDC standard response if grant_type of refresh_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect

Currently I am using `/token` endpoint to obtain an `access token`, an `ID token` (by including the `openid+offline_access` scope), and a `refresh token` for the Authorization Code flow. The value for `code` is the `authorization code` that I receive in the `response` from the `request` to the `/authorize` endpoint.

Also to refresh `access token` as well as an `ID token`, I am sending a `token request` with a `grant_type` of `refresh_token`.

Below is the reference link, I am trying similar to implement in my custom OIDC application.
https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/refresh-tokens/main/#renew-access-and-id-tokens-with-spas

Does it suppose to return both `refresh_token` and `id_token` OR both are optional if `grant_type=refresh_token` (also in token endpoint `openid+offline_access` scope added) in `OpenID Connect` concept?

Below is the link I am trying to understand.

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RefreshTokens

Answer (score 0):

When you use the refresh token, the purpose is to get a new access token. Optionally, depending on the backend configuration, you might get a new refresh token as well (if you use a one-time refresh token setup).

You never get a new ID-token back, the ID token is usually a very short-lived token (like 5 minutes) and its main purpose is to describe how the user is authenticated and who it is. The main purpose of the ID token is to create the local session (typically a session cookie), after that the ID token has no real use.

Comment: if `scope=openid+offline_access`, is it correct to return `id_token` along with `refresh_token` ?

Comment: you should always ask for the openid scope (its a requirement) and that is the one that gives you the id-token. So, yes, asking for those two will give you those tokens , if the token service is configured to provide a refresh token for your specific client.